# Save plot as audio file Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I have an audio signal in Matlab and I resized it with plot. Therefore I modified the axis with x and y values to only display the information I want. Now, I would like to know if it's possible to save this plotted signal as a new `.wav`-file.

Here is how my plot is written:

```
plot(t1,y1);
axis([T1-0.1 T1b-0.1 min(y1) max(y1)]);
```

This is how my file is read:

```
file1 = 'C:\myfile.wav';
[y1,fs1] = audioread(file1);
N1 = length(y1);
t1 = linspace(0, N1/fs1, N1);
```

Here are my signals to visualize the problem (the first is the original and the second is the one I want to save):

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to include the following: the code you are using to read the file (if you do), what format it should be saved to and where the sample rate is given. Additionally, it would be good to clarify if you 'resize' the plot with `axis` only or if you want to be able to zoom on the figure and then store the zoomed portion of the signal.

Comment: The original plot is resized with axis, it's not a zoom made on the figure, I do it in my program

Comment: I am not sure what T1 and T1b are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [audiowrite()](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/audiowrite.html) with the following parameters: filename, y, Fs

where y is the transformed signal and Fs is fs1. For example, passing `y1` and `fs1` will simply create a copy of the original file. Filename is obviously a string. Make sure that after you transform that you define y2 and pass y2 as y.

To get y2 you need to transform the signal without using the axis command. First you have to figure out the original length and the starting point:

```
% start = goes here
% original_length = goes here
length_in_ms = original_length - 0.1 * original_length
samples = round(length_in_ms * Fs);

y2 = y1(start:samples)
audiowrite(filename, y2, fs1)
```

Code not tested, but this is the basic idea.

Comment: OK, but how do I define y2, this is my problem. I don't know how to take y1 values from T1-0.1 to T1b-0.1

Comment: Where do you define T1 and T1b?

Comment: What is in_data ? Because if it's a function it does't exist.

Comment: You've been faster ;) Just take the values from the axis and recalculate it to samples. Where they are defined does not really matter.

Comment: T1 and T1b are values calculated with my program, they are t1 values.

Comment: Sorry, some old code got stuck there. It should read `y2 = y1(start:samples)`